# identify camera permissions cordova ios

Tags: ios, cordova, camera, ionic-framework

I have this little question, I need to identify whether authorized to occupy the camera or on the device. It happens that the first time ask me if I want to give permission or not. If I do not, open the capture screen but remains in black. I need to identify if you have permission or not, not having them, tell it to give it to them to fill it.

Some way?

I'm working with ionic and plug-camera cordova

Comment: latest version of the plugin includes this functionality

Comment: If, upgrade and everything works fine.